# Why Mysql Full Text Search in Jpa EntityManager Native query can't find data?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, full-text-search

### problem

---

When I try to use full text search in Spring with entity manager native query. It's not working (There is a data, but query always return empty list). But when I am not using full text search, like just `'select * from notice'`, it's working .
What's even more strange is that full text search query work well in mysql CLI or mysql work bench.

### **What I've done**

---

- change os(linux to window)
- use testcontainer
- change spring boot version (2.7.4 -> 2.6.12)
- using jdbc template

### **What I need**

---

I can't solve this problem.
There is no exception when I start my test.

I don't know why full text search isn't working.

Can you tell me what's wrong?

### **version**

---

- Mysql: 8.0.30
- spring: 2.6.12
- hibernate: 5.6.11.Final

### **My Code**

---

**Entity**

```
    package com.example.playground;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class Notice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "notice_serial")
    private Long serial;

    private String author;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private Long recommendationCount;
    private Long viewCount;
    private ZonedDateTime createTime;

    @Builder
    private Notice(Long serial, String author, String title, String content) {
        this.serial = serial;
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.createTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
        this.viewCount = 0L;
        this.recommendationCount = 0L;
    }

    public static Notice of(String author, String title, String content) {
        return Notice.builder()
                .author(author)
                .title(title)
                .content(content)
                .build();
    }

    public void update(String title, String content) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Long addViewCount() {
        return ++viewCount;
    }

    public Long addRecommendationCount() {
        return ++recommendationCount;
    }
}
```

**Test Code**

```
package com.example.playground.query;

import com.example.playground.Notice;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;

@SpringBootTest
public class queryTest {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;
    
    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        Notice notice = Notice.builder()
                .author("user")
                .title("title")
                .content("content")
                .build();
        em.persist(notice);
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void find() {
        List<Notice> lists = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM notice WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+title*');", Notice.class)
                .getResultList();

        //result return always 0
        System.out.println("lists.size() = " + lists.size());

        for (Notice list : lists) {
            System.out.println("list = " + list);
        }

        List<Notice> lists2 = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM notice", Notice.class)
                .getResultList();
        
        //result return 1
        System.out.println("lists2.size() = " + lists2.size());
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
    spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testboard
    username: admin
    password: ****
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    open-in-view: false
    show-sql: true
  sql:
    init:
      schema-locations: classpath:schema.sql
      mode: always
```

**schema.sql**

```
drop table if exists notice;

create table notice (
                        notice_serial bigint auto_increment,
                        content text,
                        create_time timestamp,
                        recommendation_count bigint,
                        title text,
                        view_count bigint,
                        author char(50), primary key (notice_serial))ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
alter table notice add fulltext index ft_title_index (title) with parser NGRAM;
alter table notice add fulltext index ft_content_index (content) with parser NGRAM;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting any parameter, e.g. the title you want to search for:

```
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM notice WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+title*');"
                     , Notice.class)
```

is searching for a title containing the actual word "title".

You need to actually put in the title you are looking for, e.g. something like

```
public void find(String title) {
    Query q = em.createNativeQuery(
         "SELECT * FROM notice WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST (:title IN BOOLEAN MODE)" 
         , Notice.class);
    q.setParameter("title", "+"+title+"*");
    List<Notice> lists = q.getResultList(); 
    ...
```

Please note that the modifiers "+" and "*" only work in `BOOLEAN MODE` (this is the same for the mysql cli though), e.g. if you do not specify that mode, specifically the wildcard won't have an effect and you will only find the exact word.

And if the search string can contain more than one word, you may want to do some work on the parameter first (e.g. clean it up, add +/* around every single word, ...).

Comment: Thank you for reply!!  parameter binding work well and I check parameter in console but It's not working...

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean by that comment. What did you check, what is not working?

Comment: I apply your advice in test code. But result list size return same as 0. so I run with debug mode because of checking parameter value in query. - q.setParameter("title", "+"+title+"*"); It's well bound. But result list always return 0

Comment: From comparison, please post the exact query you tested in the mysql cli that returns a result, and the exact call of "find()".

Comment: test query in mysql cli - SELECT * FROM notice WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+title*' IN BOOLEAN MODE); find() function query - Hibernate: SELECT * FROM notice WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)

Comment: "AGAINST (? IN" should be "AGAINST (:title" to match the parameter name (unless your jpa doesn't support named parameters). Do you actually have a title with the word "title" in it that can be found? Did you call your procedure with `find("title")`? Please post your queries as exact as possible and do not assume they are correct and make simplifications that you think do not matter.